# How to inline edit node fields in a view

Tags: 7, views

I have a table view of content node fields, and I need to be able to edit them inline.  It looks like the Edit module would work, but I'm not sure if it works with views.  When the user clicks on a field in a result row, they should be able to enter the new value, and the data for that field in that node should be updated.  It also needs to be compatible with the Field Validation module.

EDIT: This also needs to work with the Addressfield module.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [Editable Views](https://drupal.org/project/editableviews) module for inline editing

> Editable Views lets you create Views where the fields can be edited.
>   Fields show both the current value and a form to edit it. A 'Save'
>   button allows saving of all the entities shown in the View.

Comment: Does it work with Address Field?

Comment: It worked perfectly.  I'm using it in views_embed_view(), and it works great.  I'm going to add some onclick() JS to display the edit box when user clicks on the field to mimic a "real" inline editor.

Answer (score 1):

[jEditable inline content editing](https://drupal.org/project/jeditable)  module also works perfect. I used this module, by using this we can make inline edits at node output and views output too.

> The jEditable module provides integration between Drupal's CCK module and the excellent jQuery plugin, jEditable. It is implemented as a CCK formatter, which makes inline editing possible through regular **node displays**, **Panels**, **Views**, or anywhere else you can place a CCK field.
>
> Currently supported features are "click to edit" functions for text fields, number fields, date fields, node reference fields and workflow transitions.

For installation see README.txt under module directory.

Comment: Hi does this work for user profile tpl as well?