# How to enable inline editing on Views in Drupal 8?

Tags: views, 8

It is said to enable the core module "[Quick Edit](https://www.drupal.org/node/1872284)" to be able to easily edit nodes, but there still isn't an easy way to add inline editing in Views. All I want is for text fields to show as inputs which I can change, and then press edit at the bottom. Exactly what is currently achieved with "[editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields)" for Drupal 7.

Is there a way to do this in Drupal 8?

Note: Basically my question is the same as [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/85711/how-to-inline-edit-node-fields-in-a-view), but for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Quick Edit* of nodes in Views works. You can see this on the frontpage, which is a View.

However this works only for Views which show content.

If you have a View which shows content and want to choose the fields and customize the layout, you can create a custom viewmode, configure the fields there and put the layout in the twig files of the view mode.

Of course this does not provide all features of a View which shows fields and the module [*Editablefields*](https://www.drupal.org/project/editablefields). For this you would have to wait until this module is ported to D8.

Comment: I have my view as a table, but nowhere do I see a way to easily quick edit?

Comment: You can sum up my answer in two options: 1) Configure the View as content and put the table markup in twig files. 2) Wait for Editablefields

Answer (score 5):

In Drupal 8, there are now two options:

- [Views Entity Form Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field)
- [jEditable inline content editing](https://www.drupal.org/project/jeditable)