# Live Inline Editing of Fields in Views

Tags: views, 8, entities

I know Drupal 8 has the quick edit module for inline editing, but how do you turn this feature on for a View that has fields where you can just click to edit it inline?

Comment: Quick Edit of nodes in Views works. Refer [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/220373/how-to-enable-inline-editing-on-views-in-drupal-8?noredirect=1&lq=1) link.

Answer (score 4):

Quick Edit of nodes in Views works. You can see this on the frontpage, which is a View.

However this works only for Views which show content.

If you have a View which shows content and want to choose the fields and customize the layout, you can create a custom viewmode, configure the fields there and put the layout in the twig files of the view mode.

Of course this does not provide all features of a View which shows fields and the module [Editablefields](https://www.drupal.org/project/editableviews). For this you would have to wait until this module is ported to D8.

Answer (score 1):

[views_entity_form_field](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_entity_form_field) might become the replacement of editablefields module for views in Drupal 8.

> This module provides the ability to add form field widgets to a view to edit multiple entities at one time.
>
> Form field options will show up in a View's "Add field" list, prefixed with "Form field: " and then the name of the field being added.